# Is there a way to draw primitives in 3D with Python?

Tags: python, 3d, python-2.7, kde-plasma

I want to draw 3D primitives like spheres, cylinders and planes (patches) in a 3D plot and I would like to be able to interactively rotate, translate and zoom the scene. I want to do that in Python. I'm use to use Matplotlib for 2d graphs but I never worked with 3D graphics with Python.

Any suggestions?
Any link to tutorials?
Any ideas?

Comment: Via some OpenGL bindings for Python perhaps?

Comment: Yes I though about OpenGL but I beleived it was to "basic" (i.e. I would have to start from the ground to define the viewer) and I wanted something more evoluated. For example drawing a patch in a 3D plot _a la Matlab_ would be a easier way... But I don't know. Maybe it doesn't exist for Python?

Comment: Why not use [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) included in matplotlib?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html Seems you can do 3d plots using it

Comment: mplot3d in matplotlib shows 3d data set ploting (like surface plot, mesh plot) but I don't see how to plot a patch (x,y,z vertices with triangle array). Maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're used to matplotlib, then [mplot3d](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/) is probably a good option if it meets your requirements.

Alternatively there is [VPython](http://www.vpython.org/). This allows you greater freedom to create arbitrary objects and manipulate them, but, of course, more to learn.

Comment: I would also mention that blender can be controlled from pyscripts

Comment: I will add VisPy - very recent and uses GPU. Most examples is in 2d but it can also do 3d. http://vispy.org/

Comment: Thanks, @Mick_ . Haven't come across that one before. It looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

This library [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) could help. It supports [over 40 primitives](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/geometries/geometries.html).
To install it, just `pip install glass-engine`. With [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/):

1. You can use following code to show one primitive and interact with it:

```py
from glass_engine import *
from glass_engine.Geometries import *

scene, camera, light = ModelView()

cone = Cone(radius=0.5, height=1)
cone.position.z = -0.5
scene.add(cylinder)

camera.screen.show()
```

Then you can get following result:
[cone display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TDnJ.png)

you can use mouse left button drag to rotate, right button drag to translate, wheel scroll to zoom the scene.

2. You can use following code to show a lot of primitives in a scene and interact with it:

```py
from glass_engine import *
from glass_engine.Geometries import *

scene, camera, light, floor = SceneRoam()

geoms = \
[
    Sphere(radius=0.5)    , Cone(radius=0.5)        , Cylinder(radius=0.5),
    Box(Lx=0.7)           , Prism(radius=0.5)       , Pyramid(radius=0.5),
    Octahedron(radius=0.5), Dodecahedron(radius=0.5), Icosahedron(radius=0.5)
]

for i in range(len(geoms)):
    geoms[i].position.x = 2*(i % 3 - 1)
    geoms[i].position.y = 2*(1 - i // 3)
    geoms[i].position.z -= geoms[i].z_min
    scene.add(geoms[i])

camera.screen.show()
```

Then you can get following result:
[a lot of primitives scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er6uj.png)

you can use <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> to roam in scene, mouse right button drag to rotate, wheel scroll to zoom.

See full document at: [*Glass Engine Documentation*](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/index.html).

Although it's written in Chinese, you can use translator to translate it into your language.